# Getting an object from an array by the objects name in twig

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I want to store my template text in a databse table.

```
Name     |    Text                         |  .....
----------------------------------------------------
Title    | My very own Blog                | ......
Intro    | Hello stranger, this is my blog |
```

Each item is a record and I want to access each item directly in Twig.

Currently my code is:

```
public function indexAction()
{
  $ObjArr=$EntityManager->getRepository('myBundle:tplitems')->findAll();

  foreach($ObjArr as $obj) {
    $tplitems[$obj-getName()]=$obj;
  }

  return $this->render('myBundle::index.html.twig',array('tplitems'=>$tplitems,))
}
```

which lets me write in Twig:

```
{{ tplitems.title.text }}
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this ?

Comment: Better or cleaner in which context?

Comment: Is there a Twig-Function to do this? Or at least a PHP-function? I am not sure if its good practice to have a foreach construct in the controller.

Comment: That is propably because you have no model, but just a database, and need to transform it's output into the template.

Comment: No models in symfony2... I use Doctrine, which uses very simple Entities (basically just a class with setters and getters for every variable (=database-field).

Comment: In Twig I can access the name-property of my entity very simply even without the foreach-construct: {{basics.0.name}} which would in my case result in 'Title'; and {{basics.0.Text}} resulting in 'My very own Blog'. I am interested how others do this and if there for chances is a twig filter that would be better practice to use.

Comment: I'd call that a data object. A model in my view is something that does high-level logic and converts it to a convenient level for template consumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create you own repository method instead of using `findAll()`, and use doctrine's index by feature. Quoting from [the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html):

> The INDEX BY construct is nothing that directly translates into SQL but that affects object and array hydration. After each FROM and JOIN clause you specify by which field this class should be indexed in the result. By default a result is incremented by numerical keys starting with 0. However with INDEX BY you can specify any other column to be the key of your result, it really only makes sense with primary or unique fields though:

```
SELECT u.id, u.status, upper(u.name) nameUpper FROM User u INDEX BY u.id
JOIN u.phonenumbers p INDEX BY p.phonenumber
```